# Sort a hash by key containing string format

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, hash

I have an array of hashes containing strings like this:

```
array = [
  {name: "Gad", color: "blue"},
  {name: "Lad", color: "red"},
  {name: "Mad", color: "green"},
  {name: "Sad", color: "blue"},
  {name: "Sad", color: "green"}
]
```

I tried:

```
require 'pp'

array = [
  {name: "Gad", color: "blue"},
  {name: "Lad", color: "red"},
  {name: "Mad", color: "green"},
  {name: "Sad", color: "blue"},
  {name: "Sad", color: "green"}
]

pp array.partition { |x| x[:name] }
```

but the result is quiet wrong for me:

```
[[{:name=>"Gad", :color=>"blue"},
  {:name=>"Lad", :color=>"red"},
  {:name=>"Mad", :color=>"green"},
  {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"blue"},
  {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"green"}],
 []]
```

The expected result is following:

```
[[{:name=>"Gad", :color=>"blue"}],
 [{:name=>"Lad", :color=>"red"}],
 [{:name=>"Mad", :color=>"green"}],
 [{:name=>"Sad", :color=>"blue"}, {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"green"}]]
```

Comment: It's impossible. Your expected result in not a valid Ruby expression.

Comment: My output is done with pretty print (pp), here the confusion, sorry !

Comment: @Andrey Deineko OK i note that !

Comment: @all, now i think my problem and the expected are clearer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.group_by { |hash| hash[:name] }.values
# [
#   [{:name=>"Gad", :color=>"blue"}],
#   [{:name=>"Lad", :color=>"red"}],
#   [{:name=>"Mad", :color=>"green"}],
#   [{:name=>"Sad", :color=>"blue"}, {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"green"}]
# ]
```

References:

- [Enumerable#`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [Hash#`values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values)

Comment: Thanks ! This works for me too ! this one is most elegant, great !

Answer (score 2):

Using `group_by` might be better suited to this. For example:

```
array.group_by { |x| x[:name] }.map(&:last)
# => [[{:name=>"Gad", :color=>"blue"}], [{:name=>"Lad", :color=>"red"}], [{:name=>"Mad", :color=>"green"}], [{:name=>"Sad", :color=>"blue"}, {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"green"}]]
```

Comment: The edit here is pointless because now we have a duplicate answer. Although the original answer was more verbose than should be, it nonetheless worked.

Answer (score 2):

If I may say so, an array of arrays of hashes with the same name and different colors probably isn't the best format for your data.

It contains redudant information and lookup is slow and verbose.

You could build a single hash with `name` as key and and an array of `colors` :

```
array = [
  { name: 'Gad', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Lad', color: 'red' },
  { name: 'Mad', color: 'green' },
  { name: 'Sad', color: 'blue' },
  { name: 'Sad', color: 'green' }
]

colors = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

colors = array.each_with_object(colors) do |hash, colors|
  colors[hash[:name]] << hash[:color]
end

p colors
#=> {"Gad"=>["blue"], "Lad"=>["red"], "Mad"=>["green"], "Sad"=>["blue", "green"]}
```

Comment: Yes i agree, but the goal is to understand what to do with this kind of construction : array of hash => simple hash (here IMHO) or complex hash (multiple key /value with value are arry for exemple)

Comment: You haven't answered the question! Good on you! All too often SO questions have poor data structures yet no one points that out and suggests alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the form of [Hash.update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a hash to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:name]=>[g]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.values
  #=> [[{:name=>"Gad", :color=>"blue"}],
  #    [{:name=>"Lad", :color=>"red"}],
  #    [{:name=>"Mad", :color=>"green"}],
  #    [{:name=>"Sad", :color=>"blue"}, {:name=>"Sad", :color=>"green"}]]
```

To create the data structure @Eric suggested, this would be:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:name]=>[g[:color]]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"Gad"=>["blue"], "Lad"=>["red"], "Mad"=>["green"], "Sad"=>["blue", "green"]}
```